# how can I close this dropdown terminal?

Tags: command-line, mate

I must have hit something, I have a huge terminal window in the top third of my screen. (which is kinda nice, but It covering up my desktop, I don't know how I opened it, and I cant seem to close it. I tried typing `exit`, in the terminal window, but it just seems to immediately reopen. Here is a picture:

[image]

I tried moving to another workplace, but its still there.
how can I close this floating terminal?

Comment: It seems like something like this:http://www.webupd8.org/2015/05/drop-down-terminal-guake-070-released.html

Comment: Click on it to make active window then type exit hit enter ... I see a non focus prompt near top left

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like one of either [tilda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilda_(software)), [guake](http://guake.org/), or KDE's guake fork [yakuake](https://yakuake.kde.org/). Tilda's default keybinding is the tilde key (<kbd>~</kbd>) or sometimes <kbd>F12</kbd>. Both guake and yakuake bind to <kbd>F12</kbd> by default. Try pressing one of those keys and see if the terminal disappears.

You can use `apt-cache` to quickly see if one or more of these emulators are installed:

```
apt-cache policy tilda guake yakuake | grep Installed -B 1
```

From there you can either uninstall the offending application or change its keybinding.

My bet is on tilda, as it actually ships default in Ubuntu MATE 15.04.

Comment: Tilda binds to `F1` on my system.

Answer (score 1):

You can kill any GUI program with `xkill` command and selecting the appropriate window. Your bigger issue is figuring out what drop down terminal you've installed. There is yakuake and guake, but if you want more precise answer , try this:

1. Find out that shell's PID with `echo $$`.
2. Use  `pstree -p | less` to list all processes with their pids in brackets.
3. Use `/` and type in PID of that process

Or in a single command:

```
 pstree -p | grep -C 10 --color $(echo $$)
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> works fine for me.